# Factorizing a variable

Tags: r, categorical, factoring

I am trying to a factorize a variable which is  basically a count of how many food species one has eaten. My code is bring out an error and I am not sure how to fix this.

Totals is continous variable with the food count

```
Foods$count_quintile <- factor(Foods$Totals, levels = 1:5,
                                      labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"))
```

After I run this, count_quintile is still turning up empty.

Thoughts?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: hi MetabO can you run `dput(Foods)` and add the result to your question?

Answer (score 0):

###### Short answer:

You need to round the Totals column data, so it fits into the bins of the factor variable you're trying to create.

##### Longer answer:

In your question you stated that "Totals is continous variable with the food count". Creating sample data which is continuous:

```
set.seed(0)

Foods <- data.frame(
    Totals = rnorm(7, 2.5, 1)
)

    Totals
1 3.762954
2 2.173767
3 3.829799
4 3.772429
5 2.914641
6 0.960050
7 1.571433
```

As you can see, every value is some fraction between 0 and 5, with every number having so many decimal places that it is very very unlikely for any of them to be a round number *exactly*.

In `factor(Foods$Totals, levels = 1:5, labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"))`, the `levels = 1:5` part is saying that the input data is coded with the numbers 1 to 5; the first category is `1`, the second is `2`, third `3`, etc.

So when it looks at the Total column data we see above, and it doesn't see any of those values, it returns NA. Then it repeats, creating a column of NAs.

To make it work, (assuming rounding the Total is appropriate for your data!) you can round to the nearest value, and then the code will work:

```r
Foods$count_quintile <- factor(round(Foods$Totals), levels = 1:5, labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"))

    Totals count_quintile
1 3.762954             Q4
2 2.173767             Q2
3 3.829799             Q4
4 3.772429             Q4
5 2.914641             Q3
6 0.960050             Q1
7 1.571433             Q2
```

Answer (score 0):

`factor` isn't quite the right function for this. Obviously you are looking for `cut()` in which you can specify quintiles using `quantile()` or whatever for the `breaks=`.

```
Foods <- transform(Foods,
                   count_quintile=cut(Totals, 
                                      breaks=quantile(Totals, seq.int(0, 1, length.out=6)), 
                                      include.lowest=TRUE,
                                      labels=paste0('Q', 1:5)))

str(Foods$count_quintile)
# Factor w/ 5 levels "Q1","Q2","Q3",..: 5 3 4 3 1 1 5 5 3 1 ...

head(Foods)
#          foo Totals       bar count_quintile
# 1  1.3709584     17 0.5131505             Q5
# 2 -0.5646982     11 0.4687138             Q3
# 3  0.3631284     13 0.4058770             Q4
# 4  0.6328626     11 0.7304523             Q3
# 5  0.4042683      6 0.6039375             Q1
# 6 -0.1061245      6 0.8713164             Q1
```

We can do a cross-check:

```
with(Foods, tapply(Totals, count_quintile, max))
# Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 
#  7  9 11 13 21 

with(Foods, quantile(Totals, seq.int(0, 1, length.out=6)))
# 0%  20%  40%  60%  80% 100% 
#  2    7    9   11   13   21
```

---

*Data:*

```
Foods <- n <- 1000; set.seed(42); Foods <- data.frame(foo=rnorm(n), Totals=rpois(n, 10), bar=runif(n))
```